# Correct noun usage in a sentence - singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, agreement

Should the noun *position* be singular or plural in the following sentence?

> You should focus on the **position(s)** of your lips and tongue pronouncing this sound.

Comment: See also [ell.se] -- Btw, of course, it would be plural, although singular **will** work -- think why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singular.

This is a counter-intuitive, but although you are talking about two [or even three!] things (lips and tongue), you could well choose to use the singular because position means "the placement [of what is being considered] relative to other things", and so can be used to describe the situation as a whole: each thing/assemblage can only have one position at a time.  This applies even if you're talking about a set-up involving lots of different things, eg

> "The position/s of the chess pieces on the board".

You would be forced to use the plural in cases where the thing or set-up you are discussing changes its position over time and you are bringing this point out, for example:

> "Throughout the pronunciation exercise you will move your lips and
>   tongue into lots of different positions, some of which might feel
>   unusual."

Comment: I think you might like to re-read the sentence once.

Comment: @Kris - if your point is that you disagree with my answer, then please write your own answer explaining your position(s).

Comment: You have all the time in the world. Please take your time. Good Luck. And Yes, Sir, the down vote is mine.

Comment: I understand that comment even less than i did your first one.

Comment: Max Williams, thank you very much! Your explanations are very useful!

Comment: @Max I've edited to show that the consider-the-elements-separately analysis is equally valid (if less usual in this example). // You could add that the bare PP 'into position' never uses the plural form: 'The pieces were moved into position' (but this is not so with say  'The leading activists were moved into positions of power').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth this edit seems quite opinion based, and adds a lot of extra information which i wouldn't have written.  Wouldn't you have been better off writing your own answer?

Comment: By all means roll it back, but then I would feel obliged to reverse the upvote. Singular agreement is quite acceptable but by no means mandatory here. 16 000 Google hits for "position of the chess pieces", but 8000 for "positions of the chess pieces". And the relative frequencies are reversed in [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=position+of+the+chess+pieces%2Cpositions+of+the+chess+pieces&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cposition%20of%20the%20chess%20pieces%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpositions%20of%20the%20chess%20pieces%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I upvoted for the rationale you give for the choice of singular agreement here, but if you insist it's the only acceptable choice, I will have to register dissent. If Kris had posted 'It would be plural' (though he does add a confusing negation) in an answer, I would have had to show dissent with that also. // As a general principle, answers showing evidence of whether or not expressions are in general use are favoured. This helps combat the 'seems quite opinion based' impression that can arise.

Comment: Fair enough, i'll leave it.  Cheers :)